# Perlin Noise, Erlang and javascript

Tags: javascript, erlang, perlin-noise, simplex-noise

Given the same seed to the a perlin/simplex noise generation algorithm, is it possible for the same noise map to be generated, in the two different programming languages?

My usecase: a procedurally generated multiplayer world - using javascript clients, with the erlang server generating the same noise map to manage world syncing and other server related things

Instead of the server generating the noise map and having to transmit the generated values to the clients

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, if not out of the box then you can write your own PRNG function in both languages.